# Visual Basic 6 :: Cover all equations to get a specific outcome

Tags: loops, math, vb6, basic

My goal is to cover all possible equations (of whole numbers) to get to a specific number and extract the results to a text file.

**Here's my current VB6 code:**

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim myFile, parameterA, parameterB, parameterC, equalTo As Integer
myFile = FreeFile

equalTo = 10

parameterA = 0
parameterB = 0
parameterC = 0

parameterA = equalTo

Open App.Path + "\gangina.txt" For Output As #myFile

Do

 Print #myFile, Format(parameterA, "00") & " + " & Format(parameterB, "00") & " + " & Format(parameterC, "00") & " = " & equalTo

 parameterA = parameterA - 1
 parameterB = parameterB + 1

Loop Until parameterA < 0

Close #myFile

End Sub
```

Current output :

```
10 + 00 + 00 = 10
09 + 01 + 00 = 10
08 + 02 + 00 = 10
07 + 03 + 00 = 10
06 + 04 + 00 = 10
05 + 05 + 00 = 10
04 + 06 + 00 = 10
03 + 07 + 00 = 10
02 + 08 + 00 = 10
01 + 09 + 00 = 10
00 + 10 + 00 = 10
```

(...Obviously) I'm expecting to get :

```
10 + 00 + 00 = 10
00 + 10 + 00 = 10
00 + 00 + 10 = 10

09 + 01 + 00 = 10
09 + 00 + 01 = 10
```

etc...

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Does the order matter? Looks like you just need to add an internal loop that goes from (equalTo - parameterA) to 0. The outer loop decrements parameterA from equalsTo to 0. The inner loop decrements parameterB from (equalTo - parameterA) to 0. And you just calculate parameterC. You could do it with For loops instead of Do loops.

Comment: Note that `Dim myFile, parameterA, parameterB, parameterC, equalTo As Integer` is declaring myFile and the parameter variables as Variant, not Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Do loops

```
Do
    parameterB = equalTo - parameterA

    Do
        parameterC = equalTo - parameterA - parameterB

        Print #myFile, Format(parameterA, "00") & " + " & Format(parameterB, "00") & " + " & Format(parameterC, "00") & " = " & equalTo

        parameterB = parameterB - 1
    Loop Until parameterB < 0

    parameterA = parameterA - 1
Loop Until parameterA < 0
```

With For loops

```
For parameterA = equalTo To 0 Step -1
    For parameterB = (equalTo - parameterA) To 0 Step -1
        parameterC = equalTo - parameterA - parameterB

        Print #myFile, Format(parameterA, "00") & " + " & Format(parameterB, "00") & " + " & Format(parameterC, "00") & " = " & equalTo
    Next parameterB
Next parameterA
```